# jBPM 7.7x compiling error: Process Compilation error org.json.JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: jbpm, businesscentral

I have a workflow repository imported in jBPM Business Central. While using version 7.59 everything works properly but, after try the same workflow in newer versions (7.73 and 7.74) it thows the followin compiling error after clicking Build button:

`Process Compilation error org.json.JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type`

Nothing changed in the code. I import the project from an external git in both cases, and after indexing is finished, I click on the Build button. 7.59 is well, 7.74 is not, so there is nothing to do with dependencies or things like that.

Is there anyone facing the same issue (and solving it...?

Thanks!

Steps in 7.59:

1. Install business central and KIE server v7.59
2. Login and access to the projects page
3. Import an external git repository, wait for indexation to be finished
4. Click on Build button

Result => OK

Steps in 7.73 or 7.74:

1. Install business central and KIE server v7.73 or 7.74 (both fail)
2. Login and access to the projects page
3. Import an external git repository, wait for indexation to be finished
4. Click on Build button

Result: org.json.JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Problem solved after addin this dependencies:

<dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20230227</version>
    </dependency>